# plone page loads without css

Tags: plone, virtualhost

I put my plone site on a remote sever. I configured the virtual host.
When I get to the default page, it just shows as plain html format. No CSS no style.

My rewrite rule is:

```
^/(.*) http://localhost:8085/VirtualHostBase/http/interoptest-vlab.drimm.u-bordeaux1.fr:80/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [P,L]
```

The site is 
http://interoptest-vlab.drimm.u-bordeaux1.fr/
you can go and have a look.

The rest is like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName interoptest-vlab.drimm.u-bordeaux1.fr
    ServerAlias www.interop-vlab.eu
    ServerSignature On

    ProxyVia On

    # prevent your web server from being used as global HTTP proxy
    <LocationMatch "^[^/]">
      Deny from all
    </LocationMatch>

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteLogLevel 1
    Rewritelog /var/log/apache2/plone4_rewrite_log
    RewriteRule ^($|/.*) \
http://127.0.0.1:8085/VirtualHostBase/\
http/%{SERVER_NAME}:80/VirtualHostRoot$1 [L,P]

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What is your rewrite rule? Your proxy is working but your VHM URLs are rewritten incorrectly.

Comment: I've tried my rewrite on my own computer. Every thing works fine.When I put it on a remote server, the default page just shows up wrong.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add detail. Comments are not the best place for technical info like that.

Comment: Take a look at your logo link: http://interoptest-vlab.drimm.u-bordeaux1.fr/++resource++plone-logo.png; the home page is being served back directly, not the logo.  **Any** path results in the homepage. What is the rest of your Apache configuration for that site?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the excellent [RewriteRule Witch](http://betabug.ch/zope/witch) to generate your VHM rewriting configurations.

For your settings, the witch recommends you use:

```
RewriteRule ^($|/.*) \
http://127.0.0.1:8085/VirtualHostBase/\
http/%{SERVER_NAME}:80/VirtualHostRoot$1 [L,P]
```

This differs from yours in that the root is handled better, and the server name is auto-included from the browser headers, ensuring that you always use the correct server name.

However, your site is serving **just** the homepage, even a obvious [404 not found](http://interoptest-vlab.drimm.u-bordeaux1.fr/random_404) response results in the homepage. Something is rewriting your paths to discard all path information, perhaps before the VHM proxy rewrite rule is executed.

Comment: This is the site. Can you have a look? http://interoptest-vlab.drimm.u-bordeaux1.fr/

Comment: Sorry. I just shut down the server. you can click on the logo? The logo to me is just a break image.

Comment: @C-X: I checked the source, looked for the logo image URL and tried to load that directly.

Comment: Oh. I see. Weriod trouble.

Comment: I see what I got wrong. Under the site-availabe folder, there are two config files for the same site. I removed the old one and it works. Surely the old one rewrites the path. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. Not sure I was any help here. :-)

Comment: Great help. Don't deny that